# knockout.computed - access to element attribute

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have element in html, which have data-bind for css.
The field behind is ko.computed.

In the computed function, I need to access to the id of the element.

How can I get the element at the ko.computed function?

Code example:

```
    <span id="ship" style="cursor:pointer" data-bind="click:changeItem, css:computeActive" >ship</span>
    <span id="cat" style="cursor:pointer" data-bind="click:changeItam, css:computeActive" >cat</span>
    <span id="dog" style="cursor:pointer" data-bind="click:changeItem, css:computeActive" >dog</span>
```

view model:

```
 var vm = {
        computeActive: function () {
            return data.selectedItem()== (****here is the place where I want to use object id****)?
                 "activeText":"inActiveText" ;
        },           
        changeItem:  function (event, sender) {                
                data.selectedItem(sender.currentTarget.id);              
        }           
    };
```

**I don't want:**

**1. to use knockout.bindingHandler**

**2. to write separated computed-function for each element**

Comment: Can you post some code? Why do you need an element id in your computed? This is usually an anti-pattern that you need information like this in your viewmodel, so there is probably a more Knockout way of doing this...

Comment: I have add an example

Comment: Without a proper explanation *why* you don't want certain things it's not really relevant what you don't want. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

> In the computed function, I need to access to the id of the element.

No, you don't.

Your view model never needs to know anything about your view. (In other words, if it does, you're doing something wrong.)

Better view model (thanks to @xdumaine assisting):

```
function VM() {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray(['ship', 'cat', 'dog']);
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();

    self.computeActive = function (item) {
        return self.selectedItem() === item ? "activeText" : "inActiveText";
    };
    self.selectItem = function (item) {
        self.selectedItem(item);
    }           
};

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

and the view

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
  <span data-bind="click: $root.selectItem, css: $root.computeActive($data), text: $data"></span>
</div>
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/6998N/5/

Passing `$data` (i.e. the item itself) like this `css: $root.computeActive($data)` is necessary in this case because it forces KnockOut to re-evaluate the `css` binding for every item individually, every time.

See http://jsfiddle.net/6998N/4/ for an alternative approach.

Comment: Since `computeActive` is a function, you'll want to pass the item: `css: $root.computeActive($data)`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6998N/1/)

Comment: @xdumaine Knockout does that automatically.

Comment: Try it without it in the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6998N/2/ It binds the value of css to the whole function. You have to pass it.

Comment: @xdumaine Of course it does. See your modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6998N/3/ - it alerts the right data on click.

Comment: My mistake, it's not the $root or $parent thing, but the css binding doesn't work as you have it. It's not functioning even in the one you posted.

Comment: @xdumaine You are right, this does not work that way. "active" state has to be tracked with the individual items. Fiddle and answer fixed in this regard, thanks for the hint!

Comment: @xdumaine Your approach is closer to the OP's code, I've used it in my answer and put my alternative into a footnote. (I think it's not really *clean* to do it that way, though. Also I'm not sure what circumstancs trigger re-evaluation of the `css` binding in this case)

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to make custom binding handler then you can manually pass the id.

```
var vm = {
    computeActive: function (id) {
         return data.selectedItem()== id?"activeText":"inActiveText" ;
    },           
    changeItem:  function (event, sender) {                

    }           
};
```

html:-

```
 <span id="ship" style="cursor:pointer" data-bind="click:changeItem, css:computeActive('ship')" >ship</span>
 <span id="cat" style="cursor:pointer" data-bind="click:changeItem, css:computeActive('cat')" >cat</span>
 <span id="dog" style="cursor:pointer" data-bind="click:changeItem, css:computeActive(dog')" >dog</span>
```

[**Sample Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6998N/)